# Best JSON Array Set-up For Flatten in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to write a simple array of user, group, and class that will eventually be parsed in SQL and flattened so that user, group, and class are each columns. I am wondering the best JSON array and SQL syntax to achieve this result?

Edit: Updated to show an array not an object

Currently, for the array, I have:

```
[

 {   
  "user": "1",  
  "class"  : "a",
  "group"  : "a1" 
 },

 {   
  "user": "2",  
  "class"  : "b",
  "group"  : "b1" 
 }
]
```

For the SQL (Snowflake) I have

```
   with tab as (select parse_json(column1) as json
 from values(
   '[

{   
"user": "1",  
"class"  : "a",
"group"  : "a1" 
},

{   
"user": "2",  
"class"  : "b",
"group"  : "b1" 
}]'))
select * from tab,
lateral flatten(input => json) f
```

However, this gives me a table like:

```
| JSON | KEY | PATH | VALUE |
|------|-----|------|-------|
| {...}|     |[0]|  { "class": "a", "group": "a1", "user": "1" } |  
| {...}|     |[1]|  { "class": "b", "group": "b1", "user": "2" } |
```

Ultimately, what I would like is

```
| JSON | user | class | group |
|------|------|-------|-------|
| {...}| 1    |     a |     a1|
| {...}| 2    |     b |     b1|
```

What is the best JSON array set-up and SQL syntax to get this result?

**UPDATE/ANSWER**

Combining the two suggestions below, I have reached a satisfying answer:

```
with tab as (select parse_json(column1) as json
     from values(
       '[

    {   
    "user": "1",  
    "class"  : "a",
    "group"  : "a1" 
    },

    {   
    "user": "2",  
    "class"  : "b",
    "group"  : "b1" 
    }

]'))
    select json, value
    ,value:"user"::STRING  AS "user"
      ,value:class::STRING   AS class
      ,value:"group"::STRING AS "group"from tab,
    lateral flatten(input => json) f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FLATTEN` is not required. To access specific key/value `:`:

```
with tab as (
   select parse_json(column1) as json
   from values(
       '{   "user": "1",  
        "class"  : "a",
        "group"       : "a1" }')
)
select json
      ,json:"user"::STRING  AS "user"
      ,json:class::STRING   AS class
      ,json:"group"::STRING AS "group"
from tab;
```

Output:

[image]

Related: [JSON - Query Data](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial-query.html)

Comment: Using my edited example above, where there is an array with multiple users, this works after flattening and I think is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an array, but an object.

```
{   
"user": "1",  
"class"  : "a",
"group"  : "a1" 
}
```

For it to be an array,

```
[

    {   
    "user": "1",  
    "class"  : "a",
    "group"  : "a1" 
    },

    {   
    "user": "1",  
    "class"  : "a",
    "group"  : "a1" 
    }

]
```

Now this if dynamic could/sholud be flattened.

BUT if you where reading this as a file, you would want to use a Json file tupe and strip outer set true. At which point you willjust be handed objects. So dont need flatten

Comment: Apologies. In my example, I should have included more info. I will have an array just like that. Is flatten my only choice there to get 1 row per user? This will not be read in as a file.